# groovy gscam for 12.04armhf not existing?

Tags: ros-groovy, gscam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to install groovy gscam on 12.04armhf and find it likely doesn't exist since it doesn't show up in synaptic, unlike groovy gscam on x86. Before I try to build it myself, has anyone else tried it (@ahendrix)?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/107616/groovy-gscam-for-12.04armhf-not-existing-?/) by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2013-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think I built a deb of gscam for 12.04 armhf, but I was using uvc_camera successfully from debs on my robot before upgrading it to Hydro.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2013-12-10**:
Thanks for your response. Just checked, but in synaptic, "ros-groovy-uvc" gives no hits. With "sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-uvc-camera" it doesn't show or up either: Unable to locate package. I tried with uvc_camera as well, but no luck either.

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-12-10**:
Try compiling from source.

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2013-12-10**:
Checking again on x86, I find hydro-uvc-camera, not groovy. After reloading repo's on armhf, nothing again. If you used uvc_camera before hydro, was it actually groovy ?